# I want to set my WAN port speed to full duplex - TP-link 840N

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a 30 MBPS link with full duplex. While testing this link via my laptop's NIC port, I get 30 mbps download and upload. However, when testing the link via WiFi using my TP-link 840 router, I only get 12 mbps download and 6 mbps upload.

How can I get the full 30 MBPS download/upload through this router?

Comment: What WiFi connection is it (a/b/g/n)? Do you have a cable port on that router to test whenever the Wifi or the router throughput are the problem?

Comment: Hey Seth, connection standards as follows - IEEE 802.11b,g&n. yes i do have 1 WAN port and 4 LAN port on the router.

Comment: Do you get the whole 30 Mbps if you connect the laptop to one of the LAN ports of the router?

Comment: Yes seth, im getting 28mbps down and 13 mbps upload speed. But through wifi, not even 15 mbps as down speed. :(

Comment: @ArunSrinivasan Try to set the router to 802.11 B & G. So disable the N protocol. You don't need it for that speed and if you only use 802.11b&g it's a lot more stable in my experience. Other potential problems could be interference from other devices, distance to router etc... etc...

Comment: @Rik, i dont have 11B&G option. Im having 11n, 11gn mixed & 11bgn mixed options are available on my router. :( do we have any other option to fix this issue.

Comment: @ArunSrinivasan You could try setting 11n. Maybe mixing the n with b&g looses stability. But your laptop needs to have 11n capability.

Comment: @Rik. i've tried 11n, but still the issue persist. Im using MacBook pro and my wireless has 802.11ac.

Comment: @ArunSrinivasan If you look at the connection-speed of the adapter on the MacBook, what connection-speed is it? You probably need to determine if there other interference sources. Get close to the router and see if the connection train at a higher speed. You could also try other mobile devices to see at what speed they connect.

Comment: @Rik, i've checked my connection speed. It is 144Mbit/s. And my laptop is very near to wifi router too. I've checked in my mobile connection as well. In mobile, im getting ~ 20mbps as down and 17mbps as upload.

Comment: @ArunSrinivasan Then the only other thing I can think of is trying to force the adapter in the laptop to 802.11g. (Not sure how on a macbook) And otherwise I think it's just an incompatibility between your router and wifi-adapter.

Comment: @ArunSrinivasan There are several things that can affect to your network performance. The first is the protocol used in both, PC and Router. If your router supports 802.11n but your pc only 802.11g the limitat is in the pc. The real performance of a 802.11g is about 12-15Mbps, what makes me think this is the problem.

The second thing may be affecting the performance are the interferences. Although the 802.11n usually reach real speeds of 50Mbps in an enviroment with a lot of wireless networks this performance may be affected. One possible solution is change the channel of the wifi.